# Laser Detection Paint

Tags: laser, thermal-radiation, wavelength, photon-emission

Does there exist a paint which if a pulsed laser of ~1500-1600nm was fired at it it would emit visible light or IR Radation (3-5 micron)?

I have seen up-converting inks and paints but I can't find any which go as high as 1500, they seem to be 800-1000nm.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: there are sensor cards and ceramic like converters which go up to 1700nm, try to search for "IR-VIS converter". So it is at least thinkable that these converter materials are available as paint.

Comment: Edmund Scientific used to sell an "IR detector" card:  About the size of  a business card, the active area may have been smaller.  It was coated with a phosphor of some kind. You had to "charge" it under bright light.  Then, it would glow orange when it was triggered by IR radiation in some band of wavelengths. I don't remember the wavelengths, but the purpose of it was to help find the beam in an IR optical system.

Comment: @user_na I will take a look thank you

Comment: @SolomonSlow I have seen this product and it fits the bill, but we need a larger, more custom area. Thank you